# Improvement to "Our system has identified this post as possible spam" text

Tags: feature-request, design, review, flags, spam-detection

While reviewing a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/29523262) in the [Triage queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage) on SO, I (barely) noticed some text, centered with the article, and very slightly spaced from the question body:

> Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully

However, as I mentioned parenthetically, I *barely* noticed this text, because it's styled identically to the text of posts.  Could this be a bug?  Or if not, may I request that more visual difference be attached to this notice?

<sub>For the record, the post it **not** spam.</sub>

Comment: Alas! this is my second question today closed as a duplicate :(  Yes @Dude, it does.